# Images on custom module are not copied on pub/static

Tags: magento2, module, static-content

I did a custom module and added a custom css. All worked fine, but this css has some images linked directly like: `background-image:url(./img/digit-sm.png);`. And obviously has its folder img on the same level.

So I decided to change these path to `./../images/digit-sm.png` and put the img folder on (renaming it):

```
app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/images
```

The problem is magento can't find these images, but the url is **correct**:

```
http://vmagento.box/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/es_ES/images/digit-sm.png
```

So I looked inside this folder and there aren't these images. Why? I tried everything, every command, upgrade, compile, static-deploy, cache and nothing. I need to do something more? How can I indicate magento to copy these files on pub/static?

If I put manually these images everything works like a charm.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: Nope... I changed the library for one that doesn't need images, so gave up this, are u trying to do something similar?

Comment: I've an image in my custom module web/images. Which I'm using in Adminhtml layout                 `<argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/custom-admin-logo.png</argument>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, I think this was a newbie mistake, maybe because I didn't deploy static files, permissions problemes, cache, etc.

I didn't have this problem anymore